# Angular 4 tinymce two way binding not working in form

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular-forms

I am trying to implement TinyMce plugin for Angular 4, wasnt able to find a proper solution. However, I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578932/tiny-mce-two-way-binding-with-angular-2-4) providing clearly implementation of TinyMce including two-way binding – this works properly.  Therefore, I would like to use this custom component in `Angular form – NgForm`. **If i use it in form, the component has stopped working** and I am getting error of `content property is null`. Can anybody tell me how to reimplement it in order to use it with form (NgForm)?

---

**This code is taken from (little edit) link above. Without form attribute in view it works correctly.**

```js
declare let tinymce: any;

import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, forwardRef, Input, NgZone, OnDestroy,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

export const TINYMCE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => SimpleTinyComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  template: `<textarea #textArea [value]="value"></textarea>`,
  providers: [TINYMCE_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class SimpleTinyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() elementId: String;

  @ViewChild('textArea') textArea: ElementRef;

  editor: any;

  value: string;

  onChange = (_: any) => { };

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
    if (this.editor) {
      console.log(this.editor);
      console.log(this.value);
      this.editor.setContent(value);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      target: this.textArea.nativeElement,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: '/assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.zone.run(() => this.onChange(content))
        });
      }
    });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

**Does not working**

```js
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="content">Page content</label>
      <simple-tiny [(ngModel)]="page.content" name="content"></simple-tiny>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
</form>
```

**It works**

```js
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
    [...]
</form>

<simple-tiny [(ngModel)]="page.content" name="content"></simple-tiny>
```

**Component holding model**

```js
export class AddEditPageComponent implements OnInit {

  page: PageModel;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.page = new PageModel();

  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm){

  }
}
```

**Method from TinyMceComponent where I am receiving error message - `value is null.`**

```js
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
    if (this.editor) {
      this.editor.setContent(value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've added an example to my previous answer. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmxtc7?file=app/tinymce.component.ts I changed `this.editor.setContent(value || '');`

Comment: @yurzui I could not even imagine that it can be simple as that. I tried adding some conditionals, but without success. This just rocks. Thank you :)